# Wife issued short-term visa for residence in Spain as spouse of EU citizen

Tags: visa, schengen, family, spain, philippines

I'm a British citizen and my wife is Filipina. She received a visa so that she can come and join me in Spain and live here with me, as is her right as the spouse of an EU citizen.

She made it clear in her application that she was applying for a visa for residence but the visa she was given is a Type C Schengen Visa. From what I can see this is a short-term visa and she would need a Type D for residence.

I know that it doesn't matter once she's in the country as she can apply for her Resident's Card but I'm worried that they're not going to let her fly or enter at the border with a Type C visa if she doesn't have proof that she's returning to the Philippines after 90 days.

I contacted the embassy when she was first issued the visa and they confirmed it was the correct type. However, she was advised by the Commission on Filipinos Overseas (basically the Filipino government agency for people who are emigrating) that it was a tourist visa and she was unlikely to be able to enter Spain without providing proof of return flights and all that. I contacted the embassy again to triple check and they again confirmed that she had the right visa type, but really I'm not sure I trust what they say as they messed us around a bit with her visa application and didn't follow the law properly.

Is this normal for a visa for family reunification for the spouse of an EU citizen? Is it possible she'll have any problems flying on a Type C visa when she isn't intending to return after 90 days?

Any help or advice with would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the visa say that it was issued to her as the family member of an EU citizen?  If so, then it is evidence of her right to travel under directive 2004/38/EC, and as long as she travels with you, or travels to join you, she cannot be denied entry except under very limited circumstances (namely, on grounds of public health, public safety, or public policy).  If she is acknowledged to fall under the directive, then it matters not one bit whether the visa is a C or D visa, or anything else.

Comment: It doesn't say that. It was certainly issued as the family member of an EU citizen as it was free of charge (as it should be) and the big point of contention when applying was their recognizing our marriage certificate. It doesn't say it on the visa though. The only note in the observations section is 'Estancia', which I believe means 'Stay'.

Comment: The "stay" bit obviously helps, but what you should really do is have her carry your marriage certificate with her, along with any other documents you submitted when applying for the visa.  Her right to be in Spain with you is actually independent of any visa or other document, based solely on your EU citizenship and her marriage to you.  With that evidence, she could not be denied entry even if she did not have a visa.

Comment: The plan definitely is to have her carry everything she used when applying for the visa. I know she has the right to be in Spain completely and I'm not worried about her right to stay once she arrives here, I'm mostly just concerned that perhaps the airline won't allow her to fly if they see she has a short-term visa with no return flight or something like that. You and I know she has the right to be in Spain regardless of visa type but maybe they don't.

Comment: I've been looking in TIMATIC, the system airlines use to check these things, and based on that it seems you are right to be worried.  I would fly on a European airline if possible.  I won't post an answer because I don't have personal experience with this; I hope someone who does will answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. Maybe I need to bug the embassy some more.

Comment: I can't speak to the airline's likely view of this or Spain specifically but it is indeed kind of normal in this is the regular procedure in several other countries. As you wrote, there is no doubt that you have a right to enter and take up residence and logically this should be enough for the airline as well (although I understand your concern). Your wife doesn't actually need a type D visa, precisely because she is allowed to apply for a residence card within the country (whereas applying for a residence permit typically isn't allowed).

Comment: Also note that *theoretically*, holding a return ticket is not a formal requirement to enter the Schengen area. You are merely supposed to have “the means” to return to your country of residence. But obviously this might still be a lot to process for check-in agents in a far-away country, especially considering the fact that the spouses of Spanish citizens really do need a type D visa to move to Spain.

Comment: @Gala TIMATIC says something about travelers without proof of onward travel possibly being denied entry. If the airline clerk has some time on her hands, or some reason to be skeptical, that could obviously lead to problems.  Adam: I doubt bugging the embassy would help as their policy is probably to issue C visas in cases like this.

Comment: Adam: You might ask the embassy about why they didn't annotate her visa *REAGRUPACION FAMILIAR UE/EEE/SUIZA.*  See http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/doc_centre/borders/docs/Annex%2022_COMMENTS%20SECTION_14.2.2011_EN.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the continued advice guys. I've been in contact with the embassy asking exactly what the 'Estancia' note means (they just gave me the English translation into 'Stay', not helpful) and why they didn't include the 'REAGRUPACION FAMILIAR UE/EEE/SUIZA' note instead. Amazingly, they recommended we book a return flight to the Philippines to trick the airline workers. This is an actual consulate recommending we book a return flight we don't intend to use in order to shirk visa restrictions. Unbelievable.

Comment: It's not so much shirking visa restrictions, because the restrictions do not apply to your wife. It might be more accurate to say that they recognize that the document they've given you doesn't adequately express to the airline your wife's right of entry into Spain, and rather than giving you a document that does, they are suggesting a workaround.

Comment: It's a very terrible workaround. If they recognise that the visas they issue aren't likely to be recognised for what they are then that's a problem they need to address. but I feel I don't have any choice. I've gone ahead and bought a return ticket just to be safe. It wasn't that much more expensive. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @phoog Yes, indeed, that's why I wrote things like “theoretically” and “I understand your concern”. TIMATIC doesn't make the rules, however.

Comment: @Adam the type C visa is the correct type for the EU citizens's family members. And in case if the visa expires and your spouse needs to travel you can ask for extension. I can detail it if you're interested.